# Java XML conversion to Map

Tags: java, xml

For the message below, my parsing code is giving `:name #text  value`.

Why it is returing this record?

Message:

```
<emp>
<emp_name>david</emp-name>
<emp-no>123</emp-no>
</emp>
```

code:

```
final Document doc = parser.loadXml(message);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
public Map<String, String> getElementKeyValue(NodeList nodeList) {
  Map<String, String> elements = new HashMap<String, String>();
  if (nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      Node node = nodeList.item(i); // Take the node from the list
      NodeList valueNode = node.getChildNodes(); // get the children // of the node
      String value = (valueNode.item(0) != null) ? valueNode.item(0)
                            .getNodeValue() : "";
      System.out.println("name " + node.getNodeName() + "  value "
                            + value);
      elements.put(node.getNodeName(), value);
    }
  }
  return elements;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output that you are getting? and what is the expected output that you want?

Comment: name #text  value 
name emp_name  value david
name #text  value 
name emp-no  value 123

Comment: exepected: name emp_name value david ,name emp_no value 123

Answer (score 1):

The output `name #text value` stands for the text nodes that are between the tags. To avoid that in the code above, the method `getElementsByTagName("emp_name")` and `getElementsByTagName("emp-no")` could be used instead. Alternative: specifying corresponding whitespace settings for these elements in XSD.